# graph api for retire device has incorrect spelling for permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Here are the 2 results for permissions (verified using permissions preview AND manually selecting permissions for account)

1. DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All

- this is one permission i am able to consent to. properly shows okta prompt for SSO and i can sign in

2. DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PriviligedOperation.All

- this is the one that i am UNABLE to accept and seemingly the one i need. even with the aforementioned permission accepted, this one still prompts for consent. when i try to consent, the okta sso dialog box pops up really quick and goes away. behavior is not seen on the other permission. Notice that this one is SINGULAR for operation.
  Documentation and also the github issue note the same thing - plural version of the permission works, singular does not, but graph explorer seems to NEED the singular version.

Using this URL format: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my_email](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmy_email))/managedDevices/{aad_device_id}/retire

i get a 400 bad request error

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "No method match route template",
            "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/entityset/key/navigation/key/action with http verb POST for request /DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/users/{my_email}/managedDevices/{aad_device_id}/microsoft.management.services.api.retire.",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2022-04-02T00:19:33",
                "request-id": "xxxxxxxx",
                "client-request-id": "xxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried with my actual id instead of email without success - the command works if you end at managedDevices, however.

Here are other things i have tried.
Beta URL for retire (gives the error below)

```
    "code": "ResourceNotFound"
```

Object ID and Azure Device ID
Ensured using POST
No header or body, just default from graph explorer

[Exploring permissions for call in graph explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCf91.png)

[Verification of access in AAD pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4hzq.png)

[Verification of access in AAD pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFj8m.png)

[Note spelling and requirement for consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj60B.png)

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As per [intune devices manageddevice-retire /Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-retire?view=graph-rest-1.0): retire action requires both delegated and application permission type for permission DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PriviligedOperation.All

[image]

But DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All is present in portal b ut `DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PriviligedOperation.All` is not present.So you might be missing to add application permission for the availabe one in portal .Try giving **application permission** also for the same (`DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All`) along with delegated and **grant consent** for the same.

[image]

If it failed again not sure if it might be only a read-only entity that shows the state of a device and if it may not allow do any action specifically.

You can also check [Delete managedDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0)  if needed.

or  Please raise a support request  from **support+troubleshooting** pane > **new support request .**

[image]

Also see

1. [No method match route template error code for shutdown manageddevice](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7073)
2. [Method returns status code 400 · Issue microsoft graph · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3887#event-3738598815)